# Library to read numbers from a string in JS

Tags: javascript, string

I'm asking if there is a method or library that reads easily numbers this type of input strings (like competitive programming):

```
2 3
0 1 20
1 2 2
0 2 17
```

I'm finding something like [Scanner class of Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#method_summary) because it has methods to detect whether there is next number, it jumps to the next line,...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want an array of numbers, or a set of nested arrays, one for each line? You don't explain what you want to do with the numbers.

Comment: I'm going to check every number. Specifically, the second number of the first line has to be equal to the number of the next lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `parseInt` for reading numbers. Also you can get the array of numbers with strings like the ones you have provided with somehting like this:

```
var numbers = str.split(" ").map(function(item) { return parseInt(item); });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the lines, you could use the following:

```
var i, lines = [ /* your lines goes here */], row;
// get lines
for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    row = lines[i].split(' ').map(Number);
    // do something with row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is use functional programming to implement a set of methods you can use together in the way you see fit.

```
const byLine = (input) => input.split('\n');
const toInt = (el) => Number(el);
const getDigits = (el) => el.split(' ').map(toInt);
const flatten = (arr) => arr.reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c));

function scanner(input) {
  return flatten(byLine(input).map(getDigits));
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rz7opmLy/)